# what is this kind of usage, ``braces inside parentheses'', called in C?

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

```cpp
while (({bool a; a =a&&false; a;})) {
    ;
}
```

will work well.

but

```cpp
while ({bool a; a =a&&false; a;}) {
    ;
}
```

end up with

```
filename.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
filename.cc:103:10: error: expected primary-expression before ‘{’ token
   while ({bool a; a =a&&false; a;}) {
          ^
filename.cc:103:10: error: expected ‘)’ before 
‘{’ token
   while ({bool a; a =a&&false; a;}) {
         ~^
          )
filename.cc:103:35: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
   while ({bool a; a =a&&false; a;}) {
```

what keyword should i refer to if i want to learn more about it?

i have seached keywords such as ``*braces inside parentheses in C*'' but in vain

other attempts:

```cpp
while (({ ; })) {
    ;
}
```

```
filename.cc:105:16: error: could not convert ‘({...})’ from ‘void’ to ‘bool’
   while (({ ; })) {
```

it seems that `‘({...})’` is a **type**, something like **int**, **float**. am i right? or it is something like **lambda function** in c++?

---

thanks to @user2864740, @o11c, @paddy, my problem is solved. it is some kind of ``statement expression'' only available in gcc.

Comment: This is the GCC “statement expression” extension, not standard C — https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html

Comment: it's a GNU extension: statement expression. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html Presumably it doesn't work since those parens are required syntactically.

Comment: This is the first time seeing a GCC extension has made me feel physically ill.  Normally the language extensions are sorta nice.  But this one is a horrible idea.

Comment: @paddy. Now I wonder if there was some usecase for which it was really nice and we're just seeing the most abusive possible usage imaginable.

Comment: This was [from Algol68](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALGOL_68#Expressions_and_compound_statements). It is an extension of the idea that an assignment is actually an expression with the value of the assignee. Why not have some statements before that?